# 書き込みスレッドのみと排他にし、読み込みスレッド同士は排他にしないミューテックスはどのように作ったら良いですか？

Tags: c++

書き込みスレッド同士（あるいは書き込みスレッドと読み込みスレッド間）は排他にしたいですが、読み込みスレッド同士は排他にしたくないとき、どのようにしたらよいでしょうか？

前提：
スレッドwrite_threadはある値をたまに書き込むことがあります。
スレッドread_thread0、スレッドread_thread1は値を読み込むことしかしません。

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

struct Data{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};

int main(){
    Data data {0.0f,0.0f,0.0f};
    std::atomic<bool> quit=false;
    std::thread write_thread {
        [&data,&quit]{
            while(!quit){
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(20));
                data.x +=1;
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(20));
                data.y +=1;
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(20));
                data.z +=1;
            }
        }
    };
    
    auto reader = [&data,&quit](unsigned int ms){
            while(!quit){
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(ms));
                std::cout << data.x << "," << data.y << "," << data.z << std::endl;
            }
        };
    
    std::thread read_thread0 {reader, 30};
    std::thread read_thread1 {reader, 40};
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));
    quit = true;
    write_thread.join();
    read_thread0.join();
    read_thread1.join();
}
```

```
1,0,0
1,0,0
1,1,0
1,1,1
2,1,1
2,2,1
2,2,1
3,2,2
3,2,2
3,3,2
3,3,3
4,3,3

// ゾロ目で出るようにしたいが、read_thread同士が互いにロックを取り合うようなことはしたくない。
```

write_thread と read_thread0 はdataに排他的に触る。
write_thread と read_thread1 はdataに排他的に触る。
read_thread0 と read_thread1 は互いにロックを取り合わずにdataに触りたい。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::shared_mutex`を使うことで実現できます。

shared_mutex - cpprefjpから引用

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <shared_mutex>
#include <chrono>

std::mutex print_mtx;
void print_value(int x)
{
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(print_mtx);
  std::cout << x << std::endl;
}

class X {
  std::shared_mutex mtx_;
  int count_ = 0;
public:
  // 書き込み側：カウンタを加算する
  void writer()
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::shared_mutex> lock(mtx_);
    ++count_;
  }

  // 読み込み側：カウンタの値を読む
  void reader()
  {
    std::shared_lock<std::shared_mutex> lock(mtx_);
    print_value(count_);
  }
};

X obj;
void writer_thread()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
    obj.writer();
  }
}

void reader_thread()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
    obj.reader();
  }
}

int main()
{
  // 書き込みユーザー1人
  // 読み込みユーザー3人
  std::thread writer1(writer_thread);
  std::thread reader1(reader_thread);
  std::thread reader2(reader_thread);
  std::thread reader3(reader_thread);

  writer1.join();
  reader1.join();
  reader2.join();
  reader3.join();
}
```